# Is there any possible using <span> tag inside <option> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

have tried to add two texts in an option tag where the two text should be in different color. However, the below code is not working fine.. Kindly assist me what should I added in this css or js.. Also suggest me if there is any plugin to use.

```
<select name="dropdown" title="Corporate Select" class="custom-select" id="target" aria-label="Corporate Select">
                <option selected>Select</option>
                <option value="">Offers<span class="calc">New </span></option>
                <option value="">Discounts<span class="calc">New </span></option>
</select>

<style>
 option span.calc {
 color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Add `<select>` is rendered by the browser and each option can only contain `text` (not html).  If you want something more fancy you'll have to write it yourself or use a plugin.

Comment: @freedomn-m , Thanks for the comment.. Am new to this.. Do you have any suggestion on finding plugins?

Comment: @passionFinder are you looking for somthing like this > http://jsfiddle.net/YBr8S/2/

Comment: @AravindS ,  I need to have two different font colors (not background color) for the two texts inside an option. For Example, "Offers" should be in default color and the text inside span "New" should be in red. Hope it clarifies. Do we have any suggestion for this.

Comment: @passionFinder can you try this? http://jsfiddle.net/USdjj/

Comment: You could try Select2. It's a very powerful plugin with lots of options and CSS customization

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background behind the text try this:

```
<select name="dropdown" title="Corporate Select" class="custom-select" id="target" aria-label="Corporate Select">
            <option selected>Select</option>
            <option value="" style="background-color: yellow;">Offers<span class="calc">New </span></option>
            <option value="" style="background-color:red;">Discounts<span class="calc">New </span></option>
```

Or if you just want the text to be different colors:

```
<select name="dropdown" title="Corporate Select" class="custom-select" id="target" aria-label="Corporate Select">
            <option selected>Select</option>
            <option value="" style="color: yellow;">Offers<span class="calc">New </span></option>
            <option value="" style="color:red;">Discounts<span class="calc">New </span></option>
```

Comment: I need to have two different font colors for the two texts inside an option. For Example, "Offers" should be in default color and the text inside span "New" should be in red. Hope it clarifies. Do we have any suggestion for this...

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot use `<span>` tag inside the `<option>`. But you can use CSS trick here.

```
<select name="dropdown" title="Corporate Select" class="custom-select" id="target" aria-label="Corporate Select">
                <option selected>Select</option>
                <option class="yellowText" value="" style="background-color: yellow;">Offers</option>
                <option class="redText" value="" style="background-color:red;">Discounts</option>
    </select>
```

Style will be like:

```
<style>
.yellowText::after{
      content: 'New';
      height: 25px;
      width: auto;
      color: yellow;
      font-size: 14px;
}
.redText::after{
      content: 'New';
      height: 25px;
      width: auto;
      color: red`enter code here`;
      font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi @Ashutosh , have tried the CSS too... the mentioned style code doesn't show in inspect element too.. Can you help me on this